# Is there a Javascript equivalent of Dart's List.expand() method?

Tags: javascript

Dart lists have an [expand method](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.7.0/dart-core/Iterable/expand.html) which can do something like this:

```
var input = [1, 2, 3];
var duplicated = input.expand((i) => [i, i]).toList();
print(duplicated); // => [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

What is the best way to do this in Javascript?

Comment: Did you try anything your self? Like a simple loop that pushes the current element twice in a new array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.flatMap` and have the callback return an array of two items, which gets automatically flattened:

```js
var input = [1, 2, 3];
const expanded = input.flatMap(num => [num, num]);
console.log(expanded);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

```js
var input = [1,2,3];
var duplicated = input.map(i=>[i,i]).flat()
console.log(duplicated);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `flatMap` method is preferred for it's readability in this case, but just to show you there are more ways to do that:

```
var input = [1, 2, 3];
var duplicated = input.reduce((a, b) => { 
  a.push(b,b);
  return a; 
}, []);
console.log(duplicated);
```